# Xcode 4.2 - c++ include guard structure

Tags: c++, xcode, include, linker-errors, header-files

I seem to be doing something wrong with the way I use include guards. Most of the time my structuring works, but in certain circumstances like the code below, I have problems. What might be causing the problem is me using the header file "all.h" as a big collection of other header files (like "another.h" and any other header files needed).

The code will compile if code in the file "another.cpp" is commented out, so somewhere along the line there is a duplication of the function "sleepFunc" (I think), since I get the following error:

> Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
>
> ld: duplicate symbol sleepFunc(unsigned int) in
>
> /Users/(project path)/.../Another.o and
>
> /Users/(project path)/.../main.o for architecture x86_64
>
> Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1

I am using Xcode version 4.2 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.8).

During the typing of this post, I discovered the issue, which was me including the header "all.h" in "another.cpp". But if I do the thing that I had to do (#include  in "another.h", use header "another.h" in file another.cpp), it makes me unhappy, since this means all files that need other files start getting messy. I would like to have just one header file for each new file I make.

(And another question, why did the compiler duplicate the "sleepFunc", even with the include guards???)

Is there a better, more clean way to structure the include guards and/or includes?

---

### all.h

```
#ifndef IncluderTest_all_h
#define IncluderTest_all_h

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Another.h"

void sleepFunc(unsigned milliseconds);

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
void sleepFunc(unsigned milliseconds)
{
    Sleep(milliseconds);
}
#else
#include <unistd.h>
void sleepFunc(unsigned milliseconds)
{
    usleep(milliseconds * 1000); // takes microseconds
}
#endif
#endif
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "all.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    sleepFunc(500);
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

### another.h

```
#ifndef IncluderTest_another_h
#define IncluderTest_another_h

class Another{
public:
    void spunky();
};

#endif
```

### another.cpp

```
#include "all.h"

void Another::spunky(){
    printf("Very spunky");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you include all.h in two cpp files you have the Symbol repeated. Try to put the implementation of sleep into a third cpp file or use static void for the functions. The include guards are okay for what I see.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I went with putting the implementation in a separate file, as both of your fixes worked perfectly!